# Creating and connecting sqlite3 database

Tags: database, sqlite, database-connection

I am currently taking the online course "Introduction to Databases" offered by Stanford. I have downloaded sqlite3.exe as per their software guides and I also installed the Database Master application. I am currently trying to do [<s>this</s>](https://class.stanford.edu/courses/Engineering/db/2014_1/courseware/ch-sql/seq-exercise-sql_movie_query_core-ontime/) exercise.

EDIT: The exercise contains a rating.sql file which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqjDo.png)

I do not know how to create a .db3 file using a .sql file and I don't know how to connect the .db3 database to Database Master application. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I did attempt to create a .db3 file and connect it to Database Master but I was unsuccessful. Here are the steps I took:

1) Opened up cmd and cd'd to the folder where the sqlite3.exe was located (rating.sql was located in the same directory)

2)

```
    sqlite.exe rating.db3
    .read rating.sql
```

Now when I go to the file directory where sqlite3.exe is located, I see the file "rating.db3" in there.

3) I open up Database Master.

4) I click "Connect" under the Database Explorer tag -> "Add Connection" -> Choose the "SQLite" option -> Check "Browse an Existing SQLite Database" -> Choose the "rating.db3" file. When I try to connect I get an error saying "Illegal characeters in path."

Comment: you do realize people not enrolled cannot see your exercise ?

Comment: Sorry. Added link to the visual representation of how database looks like.

Comment: What is the full path of that file?

Comment: C:\Users\MyName\Downloads\Introduction to databases - Stanford\rating.db3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a path having no special characters like dashes (-). Even the spaces in the path could affect the connection string.